# Excel VBA change shape fill to an image in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a workbook for printing reports from a central dataset. The data is loaded using an index match formula which my VBA iterates through and adds 1 to the reference to get to the next set of data.

The only issue I’m having is that my images aren’t getting updated.

> cur_val = to the starting reference number

> props_cnt = to the last reference number image_path = the link to an image which is generated by an index match formula which updates as the reference number is changed

> map_path = the link to a map (image) which is generated by an index match formula which updates as the reference number is changed

> export_report_as_pdf = simple function to print to pdf

Any ideas why the image isn’t getting updated in this loop?

```
Public Sub Print_all_to_pdf()
Dim i As Integer
Dim cur_val As Integer
Dim props_cnt As Integer
Dim image_path As Variant
Dim map_path As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


cur_val = Range("Selected_Property").Value
props_cnt = Range("Max_Property").Value

For i = cur_val To props_cnt
    Range("Selected_Property").Value = i
    
    image_path = Range("Image_Path").Value
    map_path = Range("Map_Path").Value
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Image")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture _
        image_path
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
        .RotateWithObject = msoTrue
        
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Map")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture _
        map_path
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
        .RotateWithObject = msoTrue

    Call export_report_as_pdf
    
Next i

Range("Selected_Property").Value = cur_val

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What does " images aren’t getting updated" mean? Does the code return an error? If yes, which error on which code line? If not, why iterating, since `image_path` and `map_path` are always the same, the iteration variable (`i`) not being used at all? Is there, in the active sheet, a shape (or more) named "Image"? Did you check what string is returned from the used ranges? Are they the correct paths?

Comment: Does the `Range("Selected_Property")` value produce any change in `Range("Image_Path")` and `Range("Map_Path")`?

Comment: I will update the question to make it a bit clearer, but `Selected_Property`  is a named range which holds an integer reference number all of the formulas (index match) are updated every time `Next i` is called. This is updating all the other formulas when the sheet is printed to PDF, but for some reason the `Image_Path` and `Image_Path` don't seem to be getting updated and each report contains the same two images - does that make sense @FaneDuru?

Comment: I also just tried to run this code again and am getting a `Next without For` error - which isn't making sense as it was working fine yesterday and I've not edited the code? Apologies, I'm not a massive VBA user @FaneDuru

Comment: 1. So, the code didn't raise any error. I returns the same images. This was the most important issue to be stated. 2. If you tested the above code, it misses an `End With` statement to properly close `With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill`. 3. Please, try inserting of the next line `ActiveSheet.Calculate`, after `Range("Selected_Property").Value = i`. Then another line: `Debug.Print Image_Path, map_path: Stop'. The code will stop on this line. what does return in Immediate Window (`Ctrl + G`, being in VBE)? Is it what you want? If yes, press `F5`. If not, investigate what's happening.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes this is now working, it will crash when there is no image file path which okay as we are still waiting on some paths.

Comment: Try using something like `If Dir(Image_Path) = "" Then Exit For`. The same for `map_path`. It will skip such cases. You can also place a `Debug` line (before `Exit For`) to return the `i` value for the cases where the returned path is wrong. Then, test it manually and see where the problem is... When you say "crash", does Excel crush? If only an error is raised, please do not use this word to describe such a situation... Write exactly the raised error and the code line where it appears.

Comment: Okay thank you! No Excel is not crashing, it is raising an error - my bad for poor terminology!